# Trouble with input preference setting using macbook pro

Tags: customization

I am having trouble with selection and input functions working on a macbook pro. Is there a macbook pro preference setting or addon for this

Comment: I very much doubt it. Being a Macbook shouldn't change anything, all MacOS systems should behave relatively the same except for bugs/unexpected behavior.

Comment: because I only have trackpad which left clicks only....

Comment: Well, then no. There just aren't enough inputs for what a mouse is supposed to be used for (take it with a grain of salt, I've never even seen a Macbook in the wild before so I could be wrong). You really should look into getting a mouse if you are planning on taking 3D work seriously, it will make your life infinitely easier.